# CasperJS thenOpen is not opening page

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I have the following code in casper :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var LOGIN = 'username';
var PASS = 'password';

casper.start('https://www.site.com/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.capture('before.png');

   this.fillSelectors('#login', {
        '#login' : LOGIN,
        '#password' : PASS
    },true); 

     console.log('wait');

    this.wait(10000, function(){
        console.log("waited 10 seconds");
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        this.thenOpen('http://google.com/', function {
            this.echo('loading google');
        });
     });
 });
casper.run();
```

Running it produces the correct output

title
wait
waited 10 seconds
logged in title

However this section :
    this.echo('loading google');

is never executed. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: are you getting the waited 10 seconds message?

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. Also, your `fillSelectors` selectors call seems wrong. The form and the login input element inside of the form cannot have the same id.

Comment: Chris Hawkes yes ... it waits for 10 seconds and logs the message and the title.

Answer (score 0):

take this part

```
this.thenOpen('http://google.com/', function {
            this.echo('loading google');
        });
```

out of the function and make a new function

```
casper.thenOpen('http://google.com/', function {
            this.echo('loading google');
        });
```

Comment: Why? This shouldn't change anything. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: I haven't but it's from the documentation in Casper.

Comment: I added it inside the wait, outside the wait but inside the casper.start block, and outside the start block, at the same level than casper.run(), it compiles and display the messages above, but this section is never executed.

Comment: Artjom B. yes sorry, in the actual code the id of the login and the form is different, I just renamed it for the example and did not realised I was using the same Id. I will add a listener to those events. Thanks!